# How to instruct compiler to generate unaligned loads for __m128

Tags: c++, x86-64, sse, simd, intrinsics

I've got some code that works with `__m128` values.  I'm using x86-64 SSE intrinsics on these values and I find that if the values are unaligned in memory I get a crash.  This is due to my compiler (clang in this instance) generating only aligned load instructions.

Can I instruct my compiler to generate unaligned loads instead, either globally or for certain values (perhaps with an annotation of some kind)?

---

The reason I have unaligned values in the first place is that I'm trying to save memory.  I have a `struct` roughly as follows:

```
#pragma pack(push, 4)
struct Foobar {
    __m128 a;
    __m128 b;
    int c;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

I am then creating an array of these structs.  The 2nd element in the array starts at 36 bytes, which is not a multiple of 16.

I know I could switch to a structure of arrays representation, or remove the packing pragma (at the cost of increasing the size of the struct from 36 to 48 bytes); but I also know that unaligned loads aren't that expensive these days and would like to try that first.

---

**Update to answer some of the comments below:**

My actual code was closer to this:

```
struct Vector4 {
    __m128 data;
    Vector4(__m128 v) : data(v) {}
};
struct Foobar {
    Vector4 a;
    Vector4 b;
    int c;
}
```

I then have some utility functions such as:

```
inline Vector4 add( const Vector4& a, const Vector4 &b ) {
    return Vector4(_mm_add_ps(a.data, b.data));
}

inline Vector4 subtract( const Vector4& a, const Vector4& b ) {
    return Vector4(_mm_sub_ps(a.data, b.data));
}

// etc..
```

I use these utilities often in combination.  Fake example:

```
Foobar myArray[1000];
myArray[i+1].b = sub(add(myArray[i].a, myArray[i].b), myArray[i+1].a);
```

When looking at "Z Bozon"'s answer my code effectively changed into:

```
struct Vector4 {
    float data[4];
};

inline Vector4 add( const Vector4& a, const Vector4 &b ) {
    Vector4 result;
    _mm_storeu_ps(result.data, _mm_add_ps(_mm_loadu_ps(a.data), _mm_loadu_ps(b.data)));
    return result;
}
```

My concern was that when the utility functions were used in combination as above, that the generated code might have redundant load/store instructions.  It turns out this was not a problem.  I tested my compiler (clang), and it had removed them all.  I'll accept Z Bozon's answer.

Comment: Don't use `__m128` in your struct.  Use e.g `float a[4]` and explicitly do the loads and stores with `_mm_loadu_ps` and `_mm_storeu_ps`.

Comment: It sounds like OP is not only using explicit intrinsics but also getting SIMD code generated by clang due to auto vectorization in some cases ?

Comment: @PaulR, if that's the case then the OP should add that information to his question.

Comment: Yes, hard to tell, but that's my interpretation of the OP's first paragraph. Hopefully he'll stop by later and clarify.

Comment: I think that most of the compilers would generate aligned loads for getting `__m128` variables, because this data type has 16-bytes alignment defined in C language. It means that unless you specifically mock your compiler, it would make sure that value of `__m128` type is properly aligned. You force compiler to make it unaligned, which may be against the rules. I believe using `_mm_storeu_ps` as *Z boson* suggests is the only reliable solution in such case.

Comment: What exact problem are you having?  Are you seeing the compiler generate aligned loads/stores for copy-assignment?  If so, then maybe copy your structs with memcpy?  Better check the asm to make sure it's not terrible, though.  And if you take @zboson's good suggestion to use float arrays instead of `__m128`, gcc may copy each array element separately.  (There was a regression a long time ago in gcc that still hasn't been fixed, afaik, that it copies structs member-by-member instead of with wider loads/stores).  In this case we get 64b integer copies for both: http://goo.gl/Lm6TGi

Comment: @PeterCordes, interesting. I saw something like that with GCC yesterday and did not like what I saw so I moved on.  The OP says his compiler in this case is Clang. Clang copies with SSE.

Comment: If I use "float a[4]" and write my own explicit load and stores, will the compiler be able to remove redundant loads and stores that result after functions are inlined, etc?

I am currently not writing my own loads and stores, and instead using the arithmetic intrinsics directly.   E.g. _mm_max_ps(myArray[300].a, myArray[301].a), simply allowing the compiler to generate the loads.

Comment: @pauldoo: The load/store intrinsics don't force the compiler to actually emit a `movdqu/a` or `mova/ups` instruction.  Think of them more as a way to communicate alignment information to the compiler.  You might want to check that your compiler does what you expect, though.  clang optimizes away completely some stores/reloads to `float local_a[4]`, but gcc does them all.  http://goo.gl/Mxe7oR.  In any case, all compilers can fold aligned loads into other SSE instructions as memory operands if they decide that's best.  (With AVX, unaligned loads can fold, too.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you should write your data structures using standard C++ constructions (of which `__m128i` is not). When you want to use intrinsics which are are not standard C++ you "enter SSE world" through intrinsics such as `_mm_loadu_ps` and you "leave SSE world" back to standard C++ with an intrinsic such as `_mm_storeu_ps`.  Don't rely on implicit SSE loads and stores. I have seen too many mistakes on SO doing this.

In this case you should use

```
struct Foobar {
    float a[4];
    float b[4];
    int c;
};
```

then you can do

```
Foobar foo[16];
```

In this case `foo[1]` won't be 16 byte aligned but when you want to use SSE and leave standard C++ do

```
__m128 a4 = _mm_loadu_ps(foo[1].a);
__m128 b4 = _mm_loadu_ps(foo[1].b);
__m128 max = _mm_max_ps(a4,b4);
_mm_storeu_ps(array, max);
```

then go back to standard C++.

Another thing you can consider is this

```
struct Foobar {
    float a[16];
    float b[16];
    int c[4];
};
```

then to get an array of 16 of the original struct do

```
Foobar foo[4];
```

In this case as long the first element is aligned so are all the other elements.

---

If you want utility functions which act on SSE registers then don't use explicit or implicit load/stores in the utility function.  Pass const references to `__m128` and return `__m128` if you need to.

```
//SSE utility function
static inline __m128 mulk_SSE(__m128 const &a, float k)
{
    return _mm_mul_ps(_mm_set1_ps(k),a);
}

//main function
void foo(float *x, float *y n) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i+=4)
        __m128 t1 = _mm_loadu_ps(x[i]);
        __m128 t2 = mulk_SSE(x4,3.14159f);
        _mm_store_ps(&y[i], t2);
    }
}
```

The reason to use a const reference is that MSVC cannot pass `__m128` by value.  Without a const reference you get an error

> error C2719: formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned.

`__m128` for MSVC is really a union anyway.

```
typedef union __declspec(intrin_type) _CRT_ALIGN(16) __m128 {
     float               m128_f32[4];
     unsigned __int64    m128_u64[2];
     __int8              m128_i8[16];
     __int16             m128_i16[8];
     __int32             m128_i32[4];
     __int64             m128_i64[2];
     unsigned __int8     m128_u8[16];
     unsigned __int16    m128_u16[8];
     unsigned __int32    m128_u32[4];
 } __m128;
```

presumably MSVC should not have to load the union when the SSE utility functions are inlined.

---

Based on the OPs latest code update here is what I would suggest

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
struct Vector4 {
    __m128 data;
    Vector4() {
    }
    Vector4(__m128 const &v) {
        data = v;
    }
    Vector4 & load(float const *x) {
        data = _mm_loadu_ps(x);
        return *this;
    }
    void store(float *x) const {
        _mm_storeu_ps(x, data);
    }
    operator __m128() const {
        return data;
    }
};

static inline Vector4 operator + (Vector4 const & a, Vector4 const & b) {
    return _mm_add_ps(a, b);
}

static inline Vector4 operator - (Vector4 const & a, Vector4 const & b) {
    return _mm_sub_ps(a, b);
}

struct Foobar {
    float a[4];
    float b[4];
    int c;
};

int main(void)
{
    Foobar myArray[10];
    // note that myArray[0].a, myArray[0].b, and myArray[1].b should be      // initialized before doing the following 
    Vector4 a0 = Vector4().load(myArray[0].a);
    Vector4 b0 = Vector4().load(myArray[0].b);
    Vector4 a1 = Vector4().load(myArray[1].a);        
    (a0 + b0 - a1).store(myArray[1].b);
}
```

This code was based on ideas from Agner Fog's [Vector Class Library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass).

Comment: Thanks for the well written response.  This might be a repeat of a question I put into a comment above, but I want to clarify one point.

If I use the approach you suggest, and have several utility functions that each "enter" and "leave" SSE world in this way.  When I chain those functions (and lets assume they get inlined), will the compiler generally be smart enough to remove the redundant storeu/loadu operations?

Or, will I find myself having to write "pre-combined" utility functions that do several things in succession, while entering and leaving SSE world only once?

Comment: @pauldoo, can you add an example of what you mean to your question?

Comment: @pauldoo, once you have filled an SSE register with data you can pass it to a function e.g. `__m128 foo(__m128 const &a)`.  Use a const reference to keep MSVC happy.

Comment: @pauldoo, I added some text to my answer that hopefully addresses your comment.

Comment: I've added a clarification to my original question, and accepted your answer.

Comment: @pauldoo, I added a new solution based on your clarification.

Comment: Either use function to load and store data, or allign buffers properly (was it 16 bytes allignment? But using functions is better

Answer (score 2):

Clang has `-fmax-type-align`. If you set `-fmax-type-align=8` then no 16-byte aligned instruction will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing your struct to:

```
#pragma pack(push, 4)
struct Foobar {
    int c;
    __m128 a;
    __m128 b;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

That would have the same size of course, and should in theory force clang to generate unaligned loads/stores.

---

Alternatively you could use explicit unaligned loads/stores, e.g. change:

```
v = _mm_max_ps(myArray[300].a, myArray[301].a)
```

to:

```
__m128i v1 = _mm_loadu_ps((float *)&myArray[300].a);
__m128i v2 = _mm_loadu_ps((float *)&myArray[301].a);
v = _mm_max_ps(v1, v2);
```

Comment: For your alternative suggestion the OP might as well use `float a[4]`.

Comment: True - I was just adding an illustration for the current struct definition, but it would make more sense to switch to an array of floats, and that would get rid of the ugly casts too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use auto-vectorization or explicit OpenMP4/Cilk/pragmas-driven vectorization, then you can  enforce compiler to use unaligned loads for vectorized loop by using:

```
#pragma vector unaligned //for C/C++ 

CDEC$ vector unaligned ; for Fortran
```

This is primarily intended to control trade-offs between "aligned but peeled" vs. "not peeled, but unaligned". Read more details at https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/utilizing-full-vectors

This only works for Intel Compilers as far as I know. Intel Compilers also have internal compilation switch -mP2OPT_vec_alignment=6 to do the same for the whole compilation unit.

I didn't check if it could be effectively applied to implementations where intrinsics/assembly is used together with OpenMP/Cilk.